# How to carry out payment gateway process in mean stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, payment-gateway

Want to integrate payment gateway in which a post request has to be made to the gateway server.In inline php it works easily as the post request is made from html form to php to gateway server. But how would i carry this out in angular and node. Should I send a request from angular to node and then from node to gateway server?

Comment: Yes *angular->node->gateway->node->angular*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check different payment gateway documentation depending upon the one you want to integrate. Here is stripe documentation
https://stripe.com/docs/payments